# Batch Create Java Class Stubs

Tags: java, eclipse, scripting

Given a list of potential class names:
1. Alaska
.
.
.
50. Wyoming

Is there a tool that will create empty java class files for each with  supplied parameters?
I'm thinking of something like the "New...Class" dialog in Eclipse, only on steriods. :-)

Thanks in advance,
Kyle

Comment: Why not just a `State` class with a `name` property?

Comment: This is pure curiosity, but why do you want to do this? Can you give us more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you really want to make a class for every state? This sounds like a strange and wrong design decision.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if a batch new class wizard exists, but it would take as long to find one as it would to roll your own in a simple bat.  I would use a `for` loop, iterating over the contents of a file that lists the Class names to be created, and in the body of the loop `echo` the template to the newly created file, using the value from the file to both name the .java as well as to fill in the classname in the template.

EDIT:  an example bat which reads class names from a file called `classnames.txt` and creates very simple stubs:

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (classnames.txt) do call :createClass %%a

dir *.java

goto :eof

:createClass 
   echo package com.abc; > %1.java 
   echo.  >> %1.java 
   echo public class %1 {>> %1.java 
   echo      public %1() { >> %1.java 
   echo      } >> %1.java 
   echo } >> %1.java
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try enums:

```
package p;

interface Foo {
    void bar();

}

enum State implements Foo {
    Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California(new Integer(42)) {
        public void bar() {
            System.out.print("is strange ");
            super.bar();
        }

    },
    Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware, Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, NewHampshire, NewJersey, NewMexico, NewYork, NorthCarolina, NorthDakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, RhodeIsland, SouthCarolina, SouthDakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, WestVirginia, Wisconsin, Wyoming;

    State() {
        this(null);
    }

    State(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println(this + " " + object);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        for (State state : State.values())
            state.bar();
    }

    final Object object;
}
```

Comment: you'll probably want to switch the order of these statements: System.out.print("is strange "); super.bar(); Or you'll get 'is strange California'

Comment: yes. i just wanted to show how to ovveride the bar method for a specific state.